# Selenium 4.1 and Spring boot Web driver version issue

Tags: spring-boot, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to migrate gradle project with spring boot from selenium 3 to selenium 4

(implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.1')
But chrome, firefox and edge web drivers remains from selenium version 3
(org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.141.59).
If I remove spring boot dependency from project, they updates to 4.1.1

Currently using gradle version "7.3.3".
Spring boot "2.6.3".
Spring dependency management "1.0.11.RELEASE".

Any ideas why this happens, I hoped that dependency hell dissapeared with spring boot creation)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same promble, I found in spring-boot-starter-parent, there is a spring-boot-dependencies in ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.3/spring-boot-dependencies-2.6.3.pom, which declared `<selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>` in properties, so you can try add

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>4.1.2</selenium.version>
</properties>
```

in your project `pom.xml`.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots? If I change dependencies in project settings, after gradle refresh, libraries being updated back to 3.141.59.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot comes with a set of versions that are know to work together. But you can override them in your build script. In case of Gradle, add to `build.gradle`:

```
ext['selenium.version'] = '4.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because Spring Boot comes packed with a set of predefined dependecies that you can find here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.dependency-versions

In this page, you will also find, how to change predefined version. In general, you need to add `.version` to your dependency name and, in case of multiple word names, you change spaces to dashes (not needed in case of selenium).

So, to change version to most recent, type in `build.gradle` `ext['selenium.version'] = '4.4.0'` at 0 indent level. (don't add it, say inside `dependencies {}`)